# Path is matching both routes, with params, and static

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Simple problem, i have two Routes, they both match when i go to /article/submit.

```
<Route path="/article/submit" component={ requireAuth(SubmitArticlePage) } />
<Route path="/article/:articleSlug" component={ ArticlePage } />
```

I know that i could just add an extra /something to the submit path, but i was wondering what a work around could be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/article/submit" exact component={ requireAuth(SubmitArticlePage) } />
  <Route path="/article/:articleSlug" component={ ArticlePage } />
</Switch>
```

Add exact, and use switch to render only what first matches.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem though.

Comment: I think `Switch` needs to be used here since `/article/submit` still matches to `/article/:articleSlug`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. let me update

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you so much! :-)